# find $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $\frac{x^2y}{x^4+x^2+y^2}$ on $\{(x,y):0< x \leq y\}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I know that if domain of function is compact set I should look for point where gradients is $0$ because of Weierstrass theorem.
But I do not know to tackle this kind of problem.
I am not looking for solution but for advices and intuition on how to think to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at special cases, such as when $x=1$. That should tell you what the infimum is.

To find the supremum, you could view $x$ as a constant and compute the partial derivative with respect to $y$. What can you say about the critical point? Can you express it in terms of $x$? Does it occur at some $y \geq x$?